# Can't turn on dev mode

Tags: developer-options

Have gone to about device and do 7 taps on the build number but didn't work couldn't even get close to doing it. did tons of research as a noob on these stuff, by the way this is my device: TB X606F Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus. Anyways it said "Action not allowed" "If you have questions, contact your IT admin." I don't know my IT admin so can't contact. I tried everything went to xda and made a account for the first time, same here and it's getting annoying and even tried Lenovo forums but I'm speaking days apart to the guy from different countries.

Comment: While you may physically have your device, you are not the owner as it is under Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) / Mobility Device Management (MDM) control. Until the IT admin unlocks the developer mode, you can't use the device they way you want.

Comment: If an app is registered as local device admin it also can deny developer mode activation. As Morrison mentioned this is usually don't by MDM client but technically every can request device admin permission. Check your Android settings which apps have device admin permission.